# Can This Two jQuery Events Simplified into One?

Tags: jquery

I have this script :

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#uk-width-1-2-left').height($('#uk-width-1-2-right').height())
        });

        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            $('#uk-width-1-2-left').height($('#uk-width-1-2-right').height())
        });
    </script>
```

which actually do the same. but, since the event is different, I have manually separate them into 2 different of functions triggered with different events. can it be simplified into one function?

thank you and happy new year

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure it can, just use jQuery for the resize event, and trigger it on page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize.ukheight', function() {
        $('#uk-width-1-2-left').height($('#uk-width-1-2-right').height())
    }).trigger('resize.ukheight');
});
```

Comment: I would prefer separating the resize handler into a separate named function and calling that directly instead of calling `trigger`. The main reason is that `trigger` will cause all other registered handlers to also be called, which may not be what you want (since there is no resizing going on at that moment)

Comment: @JuanMendes - let me fix that for you! Namespacing avoids the issue of other handlers being called

Answer (score 1):

```
var resize = function() {
    $('#uk-width-1-2-left').height($('#uk-width-1-2-right').height())
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    resize();
});

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
```